# how to create a jar with compiled classes from a source jar in java

Tags: java, jar, compilation, javac, .class-file

I know how to create a jar from .java or .class files.

I have a `sources.jar` that contains `.java` files. I want to compile these classes and pack into a `jar` again.

for example:
This is the jar I want to compile:

`hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0-test-sources.jar`.

I did `jar xvf hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0-test-sources.jar` to extract everything.

I now have

```
    ls
    META-INF    org

    ls org/apache/hadoop/
examples    mapreduce

    ls org/apache/hadoop/examples/
TestBaileyBorweinPlouffe.java   TestWordStats.java      pi              terasort
```

As you can notice, I have two packages within `org.apache.hadoop`, "examples and mapreduce", both of which have to be compiled. And I have sub-packages within "examples" that needs to be compiled.

```
javac org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/db/TestDBJob.java
```

This compiled fine

But How can I compile recursively. I tried using wildcard '*'.

This is what I tried:

```
javac -cp org/apache/hadoop/examples/*
javac: invalid flag: org/apache/hadoop/examples/pi
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
javac org/apache/hadoop/examples/*.*
```

In the last `javac` executed above, I don't see the subpackages being compiled. only the top-level java files was compiled.

Is there a simple solution such as

`javac -jar <input.jar> <output.jar>` will result in `<output-jar>` that has compiled files in it.

**EDIT**:

To re-iterate my question:

given a jar that has only `.java` files, I want a jar file that has `.class` files in the simplest possible way

Comment: Is there no Ant or Maven build file included?

Answer (score 0):

From the DOS console

cd /dir/folder of .class files.

jar cvf name.jar

Comment: I know that. That is not my question. given a jar that has only `.java` files, I want a jar file that has `.class` files.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really dirty script I wrote to build compiled JAR out of a sources JAR. It probably won't work for everything, and doesn't even handle copying the Manifest:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 sources.jar [classpath]"
    echo
    exit 1
fi

OUT_JAR=`basename $1-compiled.jar`

rm -rf $OUT_JAR
rm -rf src
rm -rf classes

mkdir src
mkdir classes

if [ -n "$2" ]; then
  CLASSPATH="-cp $2"
fi

unzip -d src $1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Unzip failed"
  exit 1
fi

find src -name *.java | xargs javac -d classes $CLASSPATH
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Java compilation failed"
  exit 1
fi

jar cf $OUT_JAR -C classes .

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Jar creation failed"
  exit 1
fi

echo
echo "Compiled and built $OUT_JAR"
```

Also available here: https://github.com/satur9nine/sources-jar-compiler/blob/master/compile-sources-jar.sh